# How to sync two tables that are not identical?

Tags: mysql, sql, asynchronous, database-replication

I have two projects using the same data. However, this data is saved in 2 different databases. Each of these two databases has a table that is almost the same as his counterpart in the other database.

#### What I am looking for

I am looking for a method to synchronise two tables. Easier said, if `database_one.table` gets an insert, that same record needs to be inserted into `database2.table`.

#### Database and Table One

```
Table Products
| product_id | name | description | price | vat | flags |
```

#### Database and Table Two

```
Table Articles
| articleId | name_short | name | price | price_vat | extra_info | flags |
```

#### The issue

I have never used and wouldn't know how to use any method of database synchronisation. What also worries me is that the tables are not identical and so I will somehow need to map columns to one another.

For example:

```
database_one.Products.name -> database_two.articles.name_short
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: There are ways to solve this - like triggers etc, but why getting there in the first place. You can normalize the "Articles" table, and by that insert only to one table.

Comment: @YosiDahari This is just an example. The actual databases handle data on a large scale. It's near to impossible to convert all my code to use a different database to get the data. So I need it to be synced.

Comment: How about [Triggers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975877/mysql-trigger-on-insert-update-events)?

Comment: @YosiDahari Care to elaborate on this in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible method is to use triggers. You need to create trigger for insert, update and delete on database_one.table, that does coresponding operation on database2.table. I guess, that there won't be any problems with insert/update/delete between both databases. When using triggers, you can very easily map columns.
However you need to consider prons and cons of using triggers - read something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048340/when-are-database-triggers-bad) or [here](https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/5806.trigger-disadvantages). From my experience performance is very important, so if you have heavy loaded DB it is not a good idea to use triggers for data replication.
Maybe you should check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) too?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MERGE function:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1704/using-merge-in-sql-server-to-insert-update-and-delete-at-the-same-time/

Then create a procedure that runs at desired frequency or if it needs to be instant insert the merge into a trigger.